# Как обработать событие возвращения к запущенному ранее Activity?

Tags: android, activity-life-cycle

Есть `MainActivity`, который начинает работать при запуске приложения. Потом я запускаю `EditActivity`, и в нём заношу в базу данных определённые значения. При нажатии на кнопку назад, я возвращаюсь в `MainActivity`.

Как мне теперь выполнить определённую функцию `getFromDb()` в уже запущенном `Activity`? Может быть надо его заново запустить, выполнив `onCreate()`, но опять же, как?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда запускаете EditActivity используйте startActivityForResult, а после закрытия второго активити выполняйте getFromDb() в методе onActivityResult().

Comment: intRequestCode может быть любой? Это типа id?

Comment: @MrKlonwar, да.

Comment: @MrKlonwar Более того, вы можете по передаваемому `RequestCode` сделать ветвление, что если в `EditActivity` никаких изменений не вносилось (передавать 1 если изменения были и 2 - если не было, к примеру), то и обновление БД в `onActivityResult()` не запрашивать. Данный механизм [специально для этого](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/69-urok-30-podrobnee-pro-onactivityresult-zachem-nuzhny-requestcode-i-resultcode.html) предназначен, чтобы не просто получить колбэк по возврату, но и предпринять разные действия в зависимости от результатов работы вызванной активити.

Comment: @pavlofff, вы путаете с ResultCode? ведь из EditActivity в MainActivity будет возвращаться результат в ResultCode.

Comment: @NikotinN смотрите статью по ссылке в моем комментарии выше. ResultCode - успешность операции, RequestCode - маркировка возвращенного результата.

Comment: @pavlofff, RequestCode присваивается при запуске второй активити, а вы говорите о том, что с помощью него можно отследить были ли изменения во время работы второй активити. RequestCode нужен что в onactivityresult понять от какого запроса пришел результат. В вашей статье с помощью requestcode отличают результат из двух разных активити, а не то о чем вы говорите.

Comment: А точно, не проснулся еще. тогда ResultCode

Answer (score 1):

Если я правильно понял, то вы хотите обработать событие возвращения в `Activity` [`onStart()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onStart()), или, возможно, [`onRestart()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onRestart()):

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    // Переопределение обработчика события onStart()
    @Override
    protected void onStart(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onStart(savedInstanceState);

        getFromDb(); // Вызов желаемого метода обработки события
    }

    // Переопределение обработчика события onRestart()
    @Override
    protected void onRestart(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onRestart(savedInstanceState);

        getFromDb(); // Вызов желаемого метода обработки события
    }
}
```

Граф переходов состояний `Activity`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Данное решение не совсем корректно, так как чтение таблицы будет происходить не только при возврате в активити, но и при поворотах, например, что вовсе не требуется и в лучшем случае будет напрасно расходовать ресурсы на ненужные в данный момент действия.

Comment: @pavlofff: на сколько мне известно, `onRestart()` срабатывает только при возвращении к `Activity` из состояния `onStop()`, и оно не срабатывает при повороте экрана: при повороте, `Activity` проходит по вершинам  `onDestroy()` и `onCreate()`.

Comment: @pavlofff: я только что проверил: при повороте экрана `onRestart()` не вызывается, можете убедиться в этом сами. Я подозреваю, что вы немного запутались.

Comment: Мне сейчас нет возможности это проверять, к сожалению, но в любом случае первый ответ, с вызовом чтения БД по событию возврата из активити, которая внесла изменения, более правильное и логичное решение, чем хардкорное обновление в методе жизненного цикла, который вызывается при множестве действий.

Comment: @pavlofff: первое решение менее логичное: с ним вводится бессодержательный код завершения второго `Activity`, позволяющий лишь отловить событие завершения конкретного `Activity`, на тот случай, если вдруг есть какие-то другие `Activity`, которые такой возможности не имеют.

Comment: Вообще не понял, о чем вы говорите. Из первой активити вызываем вторую, редактируем данные и при закрытии второй активити обновляем данные в первой, так же можем передавать ResultCode для обработки возврата. Это правильное решение задачи в вопросе